# Retornar uma consulta com todos os dados de uma tabela para o android

Tags: php, android, web-service, http-request

Boa tarde galera, estou com uma dúvida há muito tempo mas só venho tentar tirá-la agora. Eu tenho um app que se comunica com um banco de dados online remotamente através de um Web Service PHP. Eu não tenho problemas se os dados que eu preciso retornar do meu banco de dados venham em forma de String. Por exemplo:

Quero autenticar um usuário no app Android, mando usuário e senha para a página php.
A página por sua vez consulta o usuário no banco de dados e então retorna uma String dizendo usuário encontrado ou usuário não encontrado.

A minha dúvida é a seguinte, como eu retornaria por exemplo, todos os usuários da tabela do banco de dados para o android?

Método da classe que eu obtenho resposta da requisição com servidor remotamente:

```
    /** O cliente HTTP usado para executar requisicoes HTTP. */
    private HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    /** Tempo de espera em milisegundos. */
    /** Resposta da requisicao com servidor remoto HTTP. */
    private String resposta = "";
    /** BufferedReader para o fluxo de entrada da URLConnection. Necessario para poder usar o metodo readLine(). */
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    /** Fluxo de saida para escrever dados na URLConnection. */
    OutputStream outputStream = null;        

/**
     * Faz uma requisicao com um servidor remoto HTTP atraves do metodo POST. Envia uma lista de parametros e obtem uma resposta.
     * @param url O cliente HTTP. A URL a ser feita a conexao. O endereco.
     * @param parametros A lista de parametros a serem enviados para o cliente HTTP.
     * @return A resposta do cliente HTTP.
     * @throws Exception Se houver erro em alguma etapa da requisicao
     */
    public String getHttpPost( String url, List<NameValuePair> parametros ) throws Exception {
        try {
            // Referencia do webservice.
            URI uri = new URI( url );
            // Retorna uma nova conexao para o recurso referenciado na URL.
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) uri.toURL().openConnection();
            // URLConnection permite a entrada de dados. Ele nao pode ser definido depois que a conexao e estabelecida.
            urlConnection.setDoInput( true );
            // URLConnection permite a saida de dados. Ele nao pode ser definido depois que a conexao e estabelecida.
            urlConnection.setDoOutput( true );
            // Define o comando de requisicao que sera enviado ao servidor HTTP remoto - Informacao do webservice. Este metodo so pode ser chamado antes da conexao ser feita.
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod( "POST" );

            // Obtem o fluxo de saida (Objeto OutputStream) para gravar dados na URLConnection.
            // O fluxo e um arquivo, uma pagina da web, ou uma tela, nao importa. Tudo o que importa e que voce recebe as informacoes do fluxo ou envia informacoes para esse fluxo.
            outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            // Escreve os dados no fluxo
            outputStream.write( formataParametros( parametros ).getBytes() );
            // Fecha o fluxo de saida
            outputStream.close();

            // Verifica se a resposta esta ok antes de solicitar os dados.
            if( urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK ) {
                // Obtem o fluxo de entrada (Objeto InputStream) para leitura de dados na URLConnection.
                InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream( urlConnection.getInputStream() );
                // Constroi um novo InputStreamReader no InputStream dentro dos paranteses decodificando os dados.
                reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( inputStream, "UTF-8" ) );

                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                // Aramzena os dados de leitura do fluxo de entrada.
                String line = null;

                // Enquanto houver dados a ler, armazenar em builder.
                while( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null ) {
                    builder.append(line).append("\n");
                }

                // Armazena os dados recebidos da requisacao na resposta.
                resposta = builder.toString();
            }
            else{
                // Exibe no LogCat mensagem de resposta retornada pelo servidor HTTP remoto.
                Log.i("WebService", "ResponseCode: " + urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
            }

            return resposta;
        }
        finally {
            if( ( outputStream != null ) || ( reader != null )) {
                try {
                    // Fecha o fluxo de saida.
                    outputStream.close();
                    // Fecha o fluxo de entrada.
                    reader.close();
                }
                catch( IOException ioE ) {
                    Log.e("WebService", "Erro.: ", ioE);
                }
            }
        } // Fim do finally
    }
```

***Como vocês podem ver no método acima, o tipo de retorno é String. Eu quero retornar todos os registros da minha tabela do banco de dados e não apenas uma String.***

E esse é o arquivo php, neste exemplo eu quero consultar todos os usuário no banco de dados e retornar a consulta para o Android. Eu só sei retornar valores em forma de String. ***Como eu poderia retornar todas as linhas da tabela com seus respectivos valores?***

```
<?php
        // Inclui o arquivo para conexão com o banco de dados.
        include( "conecta_database.php" );

        // Tabela do usuario que irei consultar.
        $tableUser      = "usuario";
        // Obtem os valores enviados através do método POST pelo app android. Nesse caso não usarei isso.
        $email          = urldecode($_POST['email']);
        $password       = urldecode($_POST['password']);

        // Procura por todos os usuário no banco de dados.
        $queryUser  = "SELECT * FROM `$tableUser`";

        // Executa a consulta e retorna um cursor para a variável $result".
        $result     = mysql_query( $queryUser, $connection );

        if (!$result) {
            die("Consulta invalida: " . mysql_error());
        } else {
            // Se tem registros..
            if (mysql_num_rows( $result ) > 0) {
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

                // Como retorno todos os usuários da consulta e seus respectivos dados?
            } else {
                return "String já sei retornar, quero retornar linhas de um banco de dados! :)"
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer isso seria:

1. Converter os dados da tabela do banco de dados em um array de Objetos no php
2. Transformar em [JSON](http://json.org/) os objetos.
3. Quando o android requisitar a pagina vc retorna o json
4. O android transforma em objeto o JSON que recebeu
5. Faz o que precisar fazer

Esses são os passos para resolver este problema.

Se você não quer trabalhar com objetos, vc pode simplificar da seguinte forma

```
// Se tem registros..
if (mysql_num_rows( $result ) > 0) {
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
   return json_encode($row)//transforma o array em um json
}
//...
```

No Java, no android você pode baixar uma biblioteca chamada GSON da google que manipula um JSON.
O android vai receber o JSON vc precisa convertelo para um Objeto do tipo List ou ArrayList o que você achar melhor.

Comment: Poderia me ajudar etapa por etapa? Por exemplo, como converteria os dados da tabela em um array de objetos no PHP. @Abraão.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @Abraão, irei testar e volto para dar um retorno.

Comment: consegui resolver meu problema com o JSON e GSON, estudei um pouco mais os dois e consegui resolver. Eu não os conhecia e achei muito bom. Obrigado. @Abraão.

Comment: Por nada. Passei os passos justamente para vc se aprofundar sobre cada um.